# Not able to access the gcm data response

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to access the ("gcm.notification.data") value?
I'm able to access the ("aps") value using following code :

```
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let title = alert["title"] as? NSString,let body = alert["body"] as? NSString{
print(title)
print(body)
}
```

**Message Response**

```
    [AnyHashable("gcm.notification.data"): {"status":"7809","body":"sgjh body"}, 
AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "sgjh body";
        title = "yfguhj title";
    };
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
}]
```

Comment: Are you getting `{"status":"7809","body":"sgjh body"}` this as `String` or `[String: Any]`?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal  i have no idea

Comment: try printing `let data = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"] as? String` and `let data1 = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"] as? [String:Any]`. Is both data and data1 are nil?

Comment: only data1 are shows an nil, and data shows like optional("status":"7809","body":"sgjh body")

Comment: It means your `gcm.notification.data` value is `String` type rather than `JSON` object type. Ask your backend team to provide it in json object.

Comment: is it possible to convert string to JSON object in app itself?

Comment: You can use some 3rd party library for it but it is the right way to do it. It should be handled by backend team.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let gcmData = userInfo["gcm.notification.data"] as? NSDictionary {

    for (key, value) in gcmData {

        guard let key = key as? String else { continue }

        switch (key, value) {
        case ("status", let aValue as Double): print(aValue)
        case ("body", let aValue as String): print(aValue)
        default: continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to access the ("gcm.notification.data") values not the ("aps").

Comment: Whoops sorry, accidentally typed the wrong key; updated

Comment: `guard let key` is pointless. JSON dictionary keys are  `String` by definition.

Comment: @vadian is there any solution to get the value from userInfo["gcm.notification.data"]

Comment: @SurajBhujbal see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` whcih will be triggered when you receive the notification and Try the below Code:

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
     if let notificationString = userInfo?["gcm.notification.data"] as? String {
     print(notificationString)
    let data = notificationString.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
         if let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
        {
           print (jsonDictionary["body"])
        } else {
         print("bad json")
        }
     } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
      }
    }

 }
```

Comment: i want to access status and body value under the -> let notificationData = userInfo?["gcm.notification.data"]

Comment: @SurajBhujbal your notificationData will be the dictionary and using notificationData["body"] you can access the same.

Comment: its shows error  Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: @SurajBhujbal can you try the updated code.  were you able to fetch notificationData or userinfo?

Comment: @SurajBhujbal can you check if userInfo?["gcm.notification.data"] is not a dictionary but is of any other type like array.

Comment: iits shows the value in NSString And NSObject but NSDictionary not work, its shows only nil value, if i tried with any  NSString And NSObject its shows error  Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: @SurajBhujbal fetch it as a string as shown in updated answer and the convert that string to json and then parse it. I hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: check attached screenShot

Comment: @SurajBhujbal can you comment that line and check and print only the jsonDictionary. If you are getting that or not

Comment: print -> bad json

Comment: @SurajBhujbal were you able to figure it out? ... i think you are getting the json string. You need to work on converting that string to json

Comment: how to convert String to JSON

Comment: try `if let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as?Dictionary <String: Any>`

Comment: give an error Expected '>' to complete generic argument list in <String: Any>